# target first array, first value in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have an array of arrays, how do I target the first array, first value?

```
questions: [
              [
                'Purchase only', 'Sale and purchase',
                'Sale only', 'Remortgage'
              ],
              [
                'Leasehold', 'Freehold'
              ],
              [
                'Yes', 'No'
              ]
            ]
```

so I can do this:

```
    if (this.quoteResults[1] == this.questions[0][0]) 
DOESNT WORK
```

Instead of this:

```
    if (this.quoteResults[1] ===  'Purchase only') 
THIS WORKS BUT I WANT TO USE ARRAY INDEX INSTEAD
```

Comment: what do you get with `console.log(this.questions[0][0])`?

Comment: Are you sure you have `'Purchase only'` in the data? Maybe it is in lowercase? Then  try comparing with lowercase either sides. Or, who knows you may only need to use `questions` rather than `this.questions`? Not pretty sure with your demo code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also describe "doesn't work" mean? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue arises when you use 'this'. You are able to access this.quoteResults[1] but you are not able to access 'questions'. Make sure both quoteResults and questions are in your scope when you use 'this'. Try printing questions[0][0] inside the function where you have your if statement. Because questions[0][0] is the correct way of accessing it so that is not the issue.
Also, we do not know what quoteResults[1] contains, what it's data type is.

```
var questions = [
          [
            'Purchase only', 'Sale and purchase',
            'Sale only', 'Remortgage'
          ],
          [
            'Leasehold', 'Freehold'
          ],
          [
            'Yes', 'No'
          ]
        ]
      console.log(questions[0][0]);
```

Comment: console.log(questions[0][0]) has worked, so you are right, thankyou.